# How to send Array view to controller using Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have one webpage with lot of id's(ID00001) with check box. if user can check with id's, after check user can delete that Id.

I am sending array from view to controller using Ajax call.

Here is my code:

```
    function ConfirmOnSubmit() {           
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        $(".checkBox").prop('checked',
        $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
    $("#DivRMA").dialog({
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        title: "Return Merchandise Authorization",
        buttons: {
            "Return": function () {
                var strids = new Array();
                $('input:checkbox.checkBox').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        strids.push($(this).val());                            
                    }
                });
                var options = {};                   
                options.url = "/Home/Delete";
                options.type = "POST";
                options.data = { ECSIds: strids };
                options.dataType = "json";
                options.success = function (result) {
                      //deleted success
                }
                $.ajax(options);
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

Public ActionResult Delete(string[] ECSIds)
{
   //Delete Code
}
```

View Code:

```
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value ="<%: Model.lstshpids[shp]%>";/>                    
        </td>
```

my array strids looks like `"ID000001,ID000004,ID000007,ID0000009".`
 I didn't get values to controller

Thanks
in Advance

Comment: post the code where you displaying check boxes. might be extra; is appended there.

Comment: you may try: `strids.push($(this).val().replace(';',''))`

Comment: Yes ; added i removed it. but still not getting values

Comment: i checked strids in alert. values looks like ID00001,ID00002,ID00003. if assign testing purspose var strtemp ="1234,2345,2345"; then value sent to controller. but if i send strids i didn't get.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax data type is json, so you may use JSON.stringify on the array like this:

```
options.data = { ECSIds: JSON.stringify(strids)};
```

You may find some solutions for it, just search for "ajax string to server", or some kind of this.

Comment: `dataType` is for data retrieved. `contentType` controls how the data is sent.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted should work, but it all depends on how the input stream looks. It should get converted to `ECSIds=ID001&ECSIds=ID002...`, but obviously that's not working as it should.

In that case perhaps you can force the response by using...

```
options.data = 'ECSIds=' strids.join();
```

You can also force the `contentType` (type of data you *send*) and use DiabloSteves answer:

```
options.contentType = 'application/json';
options.data = { 'ECSIds': JSON.stringify(strids) };
```